# Consolas spaces length shorter than expected in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I created a user defined language for Haml files in Notepad++. It has Consolas/10 all accross the board. The style gets applied fine except that the spaces aren't the same length of the letters. What could be wrong?

[image: Consolas on a user defined language]

**Update:**

If I set the Ruby language font to Consolas/10 the spaces do have the same length as the letters.

[image: Consolas from a predefined language]

Comment: Thats just how it is. I use that font all the time in Notepad++ and the spaces are not the same length as letters.

Comment: It's not just how it is. See update.

Comment: @Nathan: Then you're basically experiencing the same problem as Manuel is. Consolas is most definitely a fixed-width font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the end of your template file there's a GlobalStyles section. Set fontName="Consolas" everywhere there. Restart Notepad++ for the changes to take effect.

In my case the template file is "Plastic Code Wrap.xml"

Answer (score 0):

I use notepad++, and have a version of Consolas installed.  NPP version 6.1.3 (UNICODE) appears to be handling it properly.

The file I'm viewing ais a C source code file, with the encoding set to "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM".

In this instance, spaces and letters have the same width.

This doesn't answer your question, but perhaps it will add information to your search.

-- Carl

Answer (score 0):

It's the bold setting in the style that causes the problem. You have to "Enable global bold font style" in the Global Styles. I would guess italic could cause the same problem too.